# Removing Myself from Band List (IP Address Static)

Tags: filezilla

So here is my problem, I've been editing my website using FileZilla, and somehow I think I've gotten onto the Band List, whatever that is.

This is where I found my information: http://en.kioskea.net/forum/affich-92145-one-certain-site-will-not-load-help

Unfortunately, I don't have access to my router since I work in a company building, and my IP address is static.

Right now the only way I can look at my webpage is by going through a proxy or using my phone.  Is there anyway to remove myself from the Band List or to change my IP address?

Let me know if you need any more information, thanks!

Comment: It sounds as if you've tripped someone's security and they've banned your public ip address. If you're sharing the internet with others, they can't access the website as well. With a static IP and any random third party, you are out of luck. Get a new public IP or get a VPN/proxy with a dynamic network address.

Comment: Sounds like your IP address was banned. Must've been done by your hosting. There is no way to change your IP if it's static. You can contact you internet hosting provider and ask them to remove your IP from the banned list.

Comment: @SMASH I contacted Yahoo, who hosts the domain, and they said the problem isn't on their end.  They told me to contact my ISP; any idea what the problem might be if it is on the ISP's end?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

FYI - after the weekend passed, something must've been reset as I have access again.  Time passing may fix this problem some of the time.